# How to save a session in Yakuake

Tags: terminal, session

I use the Yakuake drop-down terminal and would love if it could save my session of tabs somehow. When I have 6-7 tabs open, all named and everything, it is a giant pita having to re-create that on every reboot.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a [feature request for that](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149522). Lets vote it up! =)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems like you're in luck; there's a project, [`yakuake-sessions`](https://github.com/Nekmo/yakuake-sessions), meant to provide just this:

> `ysess` is a script that gathers as much info as possible from a running yakuake instance and saves it out in INI format. It can then take this same INI file as input and (destructively! *) reconstruct the yakuake session.
>
> * As part of the reconstruction process,
> ysess destroys all current tabs in yakuake
> before restoring from the INI file.
>
> Currently, ysess will save the following information:
>
> > - tab order
> > - tab title
> > - active tab
> > - per-tab working directory
> > - per-tab active command

Comment: Works just the way I imagined it :) Cheers!

Comment: Does it work for Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: does this program still work?

Comment: Update - it does still work, at least on my Kubuntu 16.10 install. Very helpful little program, thanks for sharing

Comment: Not working on my end, Ubuntu 20.04. After executing `yess -i <file>`, it just crashes...

Comment: The original project no longer works but thankfully someone ported it to Python3. This worked for me apart from a minor bug I fixed and made a PR for. https://github.com/CDanU/yakuake-sessions